# Firefox extensions: custom autocomplete

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I've found [code sample for google autocomplete](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=8226545#p8226545) and created other components for Bing and other search providers, but I can't switch autocompletion. I use following code to change `autocompletesearch`, but it doesn't work. Component works only if I define autocompletesearch property in XUL.

```
textbox.setAttribute("autocompletesearch", engine + "-autocomplete");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around that problem by cloning and replacing input field each time I need to change autocomplete source.